# Getting error while creating Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

0
I am simply creating Elastic Beanstalk and when going to "Set up networking, database, and tags" section and enabling database section it is throwing the below error even I am not providing any parameter related to DB:

Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'db.t2.micro' (Namespace: 'aws:rds:dbinstance', OptionName: 'DBInstanceClass'): DBInstanceClass db.t2.micro not supported for mysql db engine.

I can not choose any value as the option itself is disabled now and to edit I need to enable it and when I an enabling getting the above error.

[image: Error Screen]

I tried deleting the resources available previously and nothing there in my AWS console totally empty and still getting this error.